# XCode 5 crashes on every tries to add a UIButton on Toolbar using storyboard [0x7f9fc960ef80]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I'm working on a iPad project (iOS 7).  Every times i try to add a UIButton on a UIToolbar using storyboard in XCode 5 (build 5A1413), I receive this error message:

> UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[IBUIButton ibViewControllerEffectiveSimulatedMetricsDidChange]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9fc960ef80

I started my project from scratch using XCode 5 and iOS 7 (this is not a migration from iOS 6) I tried to clean project and rebuild with no success.  I tried a search on Google for this error code but it returns 0 results.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: Are you sure, that Xcode crashes? Not your iOS application? As in, your mac doesn't show XCode anymore and you have to reopen it? Or do you mean, that your iOS application crashes?

Comment: Xcode crashes, not my application.  As mentioned in post, it crashes every times I try to add a specific control on a view in Interface Builder (drag-and-drop using StoryBoard).

Comment: How exactly are you adding the button? I added a button to a tool bar in IB, and had no problems. I'm using the same version of Xcode that you are.